# Error : ClerkInstanceContext not found : Got this error while building app for nex tjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, clerk

I have been building a threads app clone with help of Js mastery yt channel. But i got this Error of Error : ClerkInstanceContext not found.

I tried restarting the app, replacing code. But nothing changed.
What to do?
Can someone please solve it for me?

Answer (score 1):

I was also building the next.js 13 Threads App from JS Mastery and ended up with the same error.

But I fixed it. I assume there is problem in having the `<ClerkProvider>` wraped under a route group, or something like that. I moved that to the `(root)` directory and created a style-specific `layout.tsx` for the `(auth)` group and moved the styles there. And it Worked.

Here is how to fix it:

1. Open `layout.tsx` under the `(root)` directory
2. add the following code to your `(root)/layout.tsx`

```
import "./globals.css";
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import { ClerkProvider } from "@clerk/nextjs";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Threads",
  description: "A Next.js 13 Meta Threads App.",
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <ClerkProvider>
      <html lang="en">
        <body className={inter.className}>{children}</body>
      </html>
    </ClerkProvider>
  );
}
```

3. add the following code to your `(auth)/layout.tsx`

```
export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <div className="flex items-center justify-center h-screen bg-dark-1">
      {children}
    </div>
  );
}
```

If you want to change the style for the auth pages only, then you should edit the styles in `(auth)/layout.tsx` and if you want to edit the layout for the whole app then edit the `(root)/layout.tsx` like the font etc.

Answer (score 1):

you can try

```
<ClerkProvider>
  <html lang="en">
    <body className={inter.className}>{children}</body>
  </html>
```

to (root)/layout.tsx file as well

that is how I fixed this problem :)

Answer (score 0):

make sure you embed the `<html></html>` tag inside a `<ClerkProvider></ClerkProvider>` tag in your root's layout.tsx file

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap your (auth) layout.tsx with ClerkProvider and your (root) layout.tsx with ClerkProvider. Make sure you've signed in to see the changes.

Answer (score 0):

onboarding page must be async

```
 async function Page() {
      return (
        <main>
          <h1 className="head-text">Onboarding</h1>
        </main>
      );
    }
    export default Page;
```

and

pay attention to which url you request,
**/sign-in** or **/sign-up**, if you try to sign-up in the sign in url you will get an error

Answer (score 0):

just simply add  around the layout.tsx in the (root) folder

```js
export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <ClerkProvider>
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>{children}</body>
    </html>
    </ClerkProvider>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

wrapping html inside  of /root/layout.tsx fixed my problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much am following and I was stuck on that same point but this is what is used in my Layout.tsx in my (auth) directory  i changed the directory from which I obtained ClerkProvider and that saved it all but thank you all for all you do

```js
    import { ClerkProvider } from '@clerk/clerk-react';
    import { Inter } from 'next/font/google';
    import React from 'react';
    import '../globals.css';

    export const metadata = {
      title: 'Spread',
      description: 'This is not the usual app you know',
    };

    const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] });

    export default function RootLayout({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
      return (
        <ClerkProvider>
          <html lang="en">
            <body className={`${inter.className} bg-dark-1`}>
              {children}
            </body>
          </html>
        </ClerkProvider>
      );
    }
```